# Flutter VS Code Error "Connect EACCES 127.0.0.1"

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I tried to run flutter application on VS Code.It always gives the error message "Connect EACCES 127.0.0.1"

Is there any known solution?

Comment: Try to restart your PC, and then try run the flutter app again.

Comment: I tried restarting VS Code and My Laptop. No luck yet

Comment: Which OS are you on? [Similar](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/47204) thread.

Comment: I just found the issue. It was an issue with my firewall.I turned off the firewall and it works well now. Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. It was because of Firewall. I have turned on eset smart security firewall and it denies access for VS code to start Hot Reload on Specific port on Local Host.

I just Turned off firewall and it works fine now!

Answer (score 0):

127.0.0.1 is probably your computer port or your IP address